# SAGA GIS work with python API error

Tags: python, geoprocessing, python-2.7, api, saga

I want to work with python API and SAGA GIS. I am very new with this work. The first step I find one module for example Slope, Aspect, Curvature and I take with right click one python script.

python script :

```
import saga_api, sys, os

##########################################
def Call_SAGA_Module(fDEM):            # pass your input file(s) here

    # ------------------------------------
    # initialize input dataset(s)
    dem    = saga_api.SG_Get_Data_Manager().Add_Grid(unicode(fDEM))
    if dem == None or dem.is_Valid() == 0:
        print 'ERROR: loading grid [' + fDEM + ']'
        return 0

    # ------------------------------------
    # initialize output dataset(s)
    outgrid = saga_api.SG_Get_Data_Manager().Add_Grid(dem.Get_System())

    # ------------------------------------
    # call module: Slope, Aspect, Curvature
    Module = saga_api.SG_Get_Module_Library_Manager().Get_Module('ta_morphometry','0')
    Module.Get_Parameters().Get_Grid_System().Assign(dem.Get_System())

    Parms = Module.Get_Parameters() # default parameter list
    Parms.Get(unicode('ELEVATION')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # input NOT optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('SLOPE')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output NOT optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('ASPECT')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output NOT optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_GENE')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_PROF')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_PLAN')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_TANG')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_LONG')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_CROS')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_MINI')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_MAXI')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_TOTA')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_ROTO')).Set_Value(use_variable_of_dataset_here) # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('METHOD')).Set_Value(6)
    Parms.Get(unicode('UNIT_SLOPE')).Set_Value(0)
    Parms.Get(unicode('UNIT_ASPECT')).Set_Value(0)

    if Module.Execute() == 0:
        print 'Module execution failed!'
        return 0

    print
    print 'The module has been executed.'
    print 'Now you would like to save your output datasets, please edit the script to do so.'
    return 0                           # remove this line once you have edited the script

    # ------------------------------------
    # save results
    path   = os.path.split(fDEM)[0]
    if path == '':
        path = './'
    outgrid.Save(saga_api.CSG_String(path + '/outgrid'))

    print
    print 'Module successfully executed!'
    return 1

##########################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Python - Version ' + sys.version
    print saga_api.SAGA_API_Get_Version()
    print
    print 'Usage: %s <in: filename>'
    print
    print 'This is a simple template, please edit the script and add the necessary input and output file(s)!'
    print 'We will exit the script for now.'
    sys.exit()                         # remove this line once you have edited the script
    # This might look like this:
    # fDEM    = sys.argv[1]
    # if os.path.split(fDEM)[0] == '':
    #    fDEM    = './' + fDEM
    fDEM = './../test_data/test.sgrd'  # remove this line once you have edited the script

    saga_api.SG_UI_Msg_Lock(1)
    if os.name == 'nt':    # Windows
        os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ';' + os.environ['SAGA'] + '/bin/saga_vc_Win32/dll'
        saga_api.SG_Get_Module_Library_Manager().Add_Directory(os.environ['SAGA'] + '/bin/saga_vc_Win32/modules', 0)
    else:                  # Linux
        saga_api.SG_Get_Module_Library_Manager().Add_Directory(os.environ['SAGA_MLB'], 0)
    saga_api.SG_UI_Msg_Lock(0)

    Call_SAGA_Module(fDEM)             # pass your input file(s) here
```

If I run this script i get this message :

```
Python - Version 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec 5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
SAGA Application Programming Interface - Version: 2.2.7
Usage: %s <in: filename="">
This is a simple template, please edit the script and add the necessary input and output file(s)!
We will exit the script for now.
```

but how to add input and output files ? I try to use this

```
fDEM='C:\Python27\test\srtm_41_04.tif'
SLOPE='C:\Python27\test\slope.tif'
ASPECT='C:\Python27\test\aspect.tif'
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas to help me?

Is this the right way to work with saga and python api?

---

i try this to fix  the input and output but not work

```
import saga_api, sys, os

##########################################

def Call_SAGA_Module(fDEM,slope,aspect):            # pass your input file(s) here
    fDEM='C:\Python27\test\srtm_41_04.tif'
    slope='C:\Python27\test\slope.tif'
    aspect='C:\Python27\test\aspect.tif'
    # ------------------------------------
    # initialize input dataset(s)
    dem    = saga_api.SG_Get_Data_Manager().Add_Grid(unicode(fDEM))
    if dem == None or dem.is_Valid() == 0:
        print 'ERROR: loading grid [' + fDEM + ']'
        return 0

    # ------------------------------------
    # initialize output dataset(s)
    outgrid = saga_api.SG_Get_Data_Manager().Add_Grid(dem.Get_System())

    # ------------------------------------
    # call module: Slope, Aspect, Curvature
    Module = saga_api.SG_Get_Module_Library_Manager().Get_Module('ta_morphometry','0')
    Module.Get_Parameters().Get_Grid_System().Assign(dem.Get_System())

    Parms = Module.Get_Parameters() # default parameter list
    Parms.Get(unicode('ELEVATION')).Set_Value(fDEM) # input NOT optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('SLOPE')).Set_Value(slope) # output NOT optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('ASPECT')).Set_Value(aspect) # output NOT optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_GENE')).Set_Value() # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_PROF')).Set_Value() # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_PLAN')).Set_Value() # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_TANG')).Set_Value() # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_LONG')).Set_Value() # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_CROS')).Set_Value() # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_MINI')).Set_Value() # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_MAXI')).Set_Value() # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_TOTA')).Set_Value() # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('C_ROTO')).Set_Value() # output optional grid
    Parms.Get(unicode('METHOD')).Set_Value(6)
    Parms.Get(unicode('UNIT_SLOPE')).Set_Value(0)
    Parms.Get(unicode('UNIT_ASPECT')).Set_Value(0)

    if Module.Execute() == 0:
        print 'Module execution failed!'
        return 0

    print
    print 'The module has been executed.'
    print 'Now you would like to save your output datasets, please edit the script to do so.'
    return 0                           # remove this line once you have edited the script

    # ------------------------------------
    # save results
    path   = os.path.split(fDEM)[0]
    if path == '':
        path = './'
    outgrid.Save(saga_api.CSG_String(path + '/outgrid'))

    print
    print 'Module successfully executed!'
    return 1

##########################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Python - Version ' + sys.version
    print saga_api.SAGA_API_Get_Version()
    print
    print 'Usage: %s <in: filename>'
    print
    print 'This is a simple template, please edit the script and add the necessary input and output file(s)!'
    print 'We will exit the script for now.'
    sys.exit()                         # remove this line once you have edited the script
    # This might look like this:
    #fDEM    = sys.argv[1]
    #if os.path.split(fDEM)[0] == '':
    #fDEM = './' + fDEM
    #fDEM = './../test_data/test.sgrd'  # remove this line once you have edited the script


    saga_api.SG_UI_Msg_Lock(1)
    if os.name == 'nt':    # Windows
        os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ';' + os.environ['SAGA'] + '/bin/saga_vc_Win32/dll'
        saga_api.SG_Get_Module_Library_Manager().Add_Directory(os.environ['SAGA'] + '/bin/saga_vc_Win32/modules', 0)
    else:                  # Linux
        saga_api.SG_Get_Module_Library_Manager().Add_Directory(os.environ['SAGA_MLB'], 0)
    saga_api.SG_UI_Msg_Lock(0)

    Call_SAGA_Module(fDEM,slope,aspect)             # pass your input file(s) here
```